# Error: Could not get the file's extension |How do save an image to Media Library in React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, expo

```
    import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
    import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';

   const handleDownloadImage = async () => {
        await MediaLibrary.requestPermissionsAsync();
        const localuri = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
            'https://64.media.tumblr.com/a92e72902106507c59ff8d0ca26abfc0/1d7f633f39b0a908-34/s1280x1920/a7073bbdeb1033b989e040fd216266be8ba31341.jpg',
            FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'demo.jpg'
        );
        const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(localuri.toString());
        const album = await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('DownLoads', asset);
        console.log(album);
    };
```

I was unable to save an image to the download folder,
I used expo without 2 folders android and ios

Comment: The folder is called: Download.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I save an image to Media Library in React Native Expo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66876415/how-do-i-save-an-image-to-media-library-in-react-native-expo)

Answer (score 1):

this code will achieve what you need, hope it helps

```js
//use these imports
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';
import * as Sharing from 'expo-sharing';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import * as MediaLibrary from 'expo-media-library';


const Download = async (url: string, name: string) => {
    setLoading(true);
    let remoteUrl = `${BASE_URL_NO_API}${url}`;
    let localPath = FileSystem.documentDirectory + name;

    let downloadedFile = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(remoteUrl, localPath);

    if (downloadedFile.status != 200) {
      Alert.alert('error', 'error in downloading file');
      // handleError();
      setLoading(false);
    }

    //handle ios non image files first

    const imageFileExts = ['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'heic', 'webp', 'bmp', 'jpeg'];

    if (
      Platform.OS == 'ios' &&
      imageFileExts.every(x => !downloadedFile.uri.endsWith(x))
    ) {
      const UTI = 'public.item';
      const shareResult = await Sharing.shareAsync(downloadedFile.uri, { UTI });
      Alert.alert('Success', 'File Saved');
      setLoading(false);
    }

    const perm = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.MEDIA_LIBRARY);
    if (perm.status != 'granted') {
      setLoading(false);
      return;
    }

    try {
      const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(downloadedFile.uri);
      const album = await MediaLibrary.getAlbumAsync('Download');
      if (album == null) {
        await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync('Download', asset, false);

        if (imageFileExts.every(x => !downloadedFile.uri.endsWith(x))) {
          Alert.alert('Success', 'File Saved To Download Folder');
          setLoading(false);
        } else {
          Alert.alert('Success', 'Image Saved To Gallery');
          setLoading(false);
        }
      } else {
        await MediaLibrary.addAssetsToAlbumAsync([asset], album, false);
        if (imageFileExts.every(x => !downloadedFile.uri.endsWith(x))) {
          Alert.alert('Success', 'File Saved To Download Folder');
          setLoading(false);
        } else {
          Alert.alert('Success', 'Image Saved To Gallery');
          setLoading(false);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      Alert.alert('error', 'error in saving file');
      setLoading(false);
      //   handleError(e);
    }
  };
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32287275)